# Splitting a string (previously code) where I want to separate the int's and string's | strings contain the separator

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split a string for example

```
String line = "(0, 10, 20, 'string value, 1, 2, 2', 100, 'another string', 'string, string, text', 0)";
```

I would like to have it split so I would have "0", "10", "20", "string value, 1, 2, 2" and so on rather than "0", "10", "20", "'string value", "1", "2", "2".

Comment: And what have you tried. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific please.

Comment: What's unclear about this?  He wants to split at the commas that _aren't_ inside the single quotes, and to drop the single quotes.  So the single quotes turn `string value, 1, 2, 2` into one unit that is not to be divided at the commas; whereas the commas between `0, 10, 20` and so on _do_ result in a split.  What a shame that I can't give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (try to be more specific :) ) you want to split up the string to achieve the following output:

```
"0","10","20","string value, 1, 2, 2","100","another string","string, string, text","0"
```

I was keen to have a go at this so here it is:

```
String line = "(0, 10, 20, 'string value, 1, 2, 2', 100, 'another string', 'string, string, text', 0)";
    char splitString[] = line.toCharArray();
    List<String> foundStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int x = 0; x < splitString.length;x++){
        String found = "";
        if (Character.isDigit(splitString[x])) {
            while(Character.isDigit(splitString[x])) {
                found += Character.toString(splitString[x]);
                x++;
            }
            foundStrings.add(found);
            x --;
        }
        if (x < splitString.length) {
            int count = 0;
            int indexOfNext = 0;
            if (splitString[x] == '\'') {
                int startIndex = x + 1;
                count = startIndex;
                char currentChar = 0;
                char c = '\'';
                while(currentChar != c) {
                    currentChar = splitString[count];
                    count ++;
                    currentChar = splitString[count];
                }
                indexOfNext = count;
                for (int j = startIndex; j < indexOfNext; j++){
                    found += Character.toString(splitString[j]);
                }
                foundStrings.add(found.trim());
                x = indexOfNext;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < foundStrings.size();p++) {
        if (p > 0) System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print("\"" + foundStrings.get(p) + "\"");
    }
```

Others probably have a more elegant solution. Good luck!